# Blazor Server App, Razor View is open in blank page instead like Weather forecast example

Tags: razor-pages, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm suffering since weeks to solve the problem. I know that I miss something, but I don't know what. Seeing other examples, it just works for them.

I created a new "Blazor Server App". And a StudentsController.

```
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(GetStudents());
    }
```

Clicking "Add View" in the Controller, I've created a new Scaffolded Item "Razor View". This will create Index.cshtml in "/Views/Students"

In Startup.cs I've added:

```
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Students}/{action=Index}");
```

And in NavMenu.razor I added it to the menu:

```
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/Students">
            <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Students
        </NavLink>
    </li>
```

This is the result starting it:

[image]

Navigation etc. is gone, but should look similar to Weather forecast example:
[image]

Comment: Example: https://github.com/rmoergeli/BlazorAppTest2

Comment: You have combined a Server-Side Blazor application with an MVC application. Your Students View belongs to the MVC part of the application. It cannot share a layout with a Blazor application. You probably intended to create a Razor Component for your students view, similar to the FetchData component that displays the weather forecast. You should spend a bit of time reading the docs to understand how Blazor works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0